# how do I get MP3 stream poster image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

For html5 audio element, using Javasript I can control behavior of audio element like this

**Play/Pause**

```
activeSong = document.getElementById("mainPlayer");
activeSong.play();
activeSong.pause();
```

**For getting metadata I am using**

```
    activeSong.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        console.log("Playing " + activeSong.src + ", for: " + activeSong.duration + "seconds.");
        $("#playListSeekBar .timers#timeLeft").html(String(Math.round(activeSong.duration)).toMMSS() + "");
    });
```

My Question is how do I get poster of currently played MP3 stream if available?

Comment: are we talking Embedded image data in an mp3 file?

Comment: @VeXii yup that's what I am talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not possible using html5 media api. but António Afonso`s [id3 lib](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader) reader can.

Comment: Perfect, was looking for the exact same thing :)